# How to process muti-dimension numpy array values using information from some dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array (X, Y, Z). I would like to re-determine the values in the array (could be all 3D) based on Z=1 and Z=2 values.

So far, I use np.ndindex to set conditions but it's slow since it iterates over all x, y positions.
Is there a more efficient way to to it ?
Thanks!

One of my example code is

```
    for i, j in np.ndindex(row, col):
        if arr[i, j, 1] > 80 or arr[i, j, 2] < 22:
            arr[i, j, 1] = 0
            arr[i, j, 2] = 0
            arr[i, j, 0] = 0
```

Comment: What is the shape of `arr`?

Comment: The x,y could be large, like (3000, 4000, 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean indexing is what you are searching for, I think:

```
condition = (arr[:, :, 1] > 80) | (arr[:, :, 2] < 22) # get condition mask
#assign the arr on all three dimensions
arr[condition, 1] = 0 
arr[condition, 2] = 0
arr[condition, 0] = 0
```

Comment: I am answering from my phone, sorry for bad formatting, will fix it later

Answer (score 2):

You can create a boolean mask with your conditions and use that to index the array. Since you are setting the entire last axis to 0, you don't need to index anything beyond the mask.

```py
cond = (arr[...,1] > 80) | (arr[...,2] < 22)
arr[cond] = 0
```

Comment: didn't realize that it had only 3 levels of the 3d dimension while posting my answer, well done! I need to sleep...

Comment: @TinoD I think you might have answered right before OP responded to my comment.

Comment: Ah yeah, just noticed also...

Answer (score 0):

```
indices = arr[:,:,1] > 80 | arr[:,:,2] < 22
arr[indices] = 0
```